# trying to get the war file from Jhipster project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, jhipster, gradle-plugin

i'm trying to get the war file from Jhipster project project using this command

```
./gradlew -Pprod -Pwar clean bootWar
```

**this the error that i got**

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'bootWar' not found in root project 'account'. Some candidates are: 'bootRun'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

---

**this my bild.gradle**

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:1.4.17"
        //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.13"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.13"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.13"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.3.RELEASE"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
}

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility=1.8
targetCompatibility=1.8

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = [ '-Xmx512m','-Xms256m']
}

// Until JHipster supports JDK 9
assert System.properties['java.specification.version'] == '1.8'

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:' + jhipster_dependencies_version
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-dependency-management - JHipster will add additional dependencies management here
  }
}

defaultTasks 'bootRun'

group = 'com.skywriter.account'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = ''

bootRepackage {
   mainClass = 'com.skywriter.account.AccountApp'
}

war {

}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.skywriter.account.AccountApp'
    executable = true
    buildInfo()
}

if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
    task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
        dependsOn configurations.runtime
        appendix = 'pathing'

        doFirst {
            manifest {
                attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {
                    it.toURI().toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/').replaceAll(' ', '%20')
                }.join(' ')
            }
        }
    }

    bootRun {
        addResources = false
        dependsOn pathingJar
        doFirst {
            classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/java/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", pathingJar.archivePath)
        }
    }
} else {
    bootRun {
        addResources = false
    }
}

test {
    exclude '**/CucumberTest*'

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task cucumberTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Execute cucumber BDD tests."
    group = "verification"
    include '**/CucumberTest*'

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

check.dependsOn cucumberTest
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn test
}

task cucumberTestReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn cucumberTest
}

apply from: 'gradle/docker.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/liquibase.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/mapstruct.gradle'
//jhipster-needle-gradle-apply-from - JHipster will add additional gradle scripts to be applied here

if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_prod.gradle'
}
if (project.hasProperty('stage')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_stage.gradle'
}
if (project.hasProperty('demo')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_demo.gradle'
} 
if (project.hasProperty('aws')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_aws.gradle'
} 
if (project.hasProperty('devtest')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_devtest.gradle'
} 
if (project.hasProperty('aws')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_aws.gradle'
} 
else {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_dev.gradle'
}

if (project.hasProperty('graphite')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/graphite.gradle'
}

if (project.hasProperty('prometheus')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/prometheus.gradle'
}

if (project.hasProperty('zipkin')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/zipkin.gradle'
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.logz.logback:logzio-logback-appender:v1.0.21'   
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
    compile "io.github.jhipster:jhipster"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet"
    compile "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets"
    compile "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner"
    compile "com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-hibernate52"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring"
    compile "javax.cache:cache-api"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
    compile "com.zaxxer:HikariCP"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    compile "commons-io:commons-io"
    compile "javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator"
    compile "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    compile "com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    compile "org.zalando:problem-spring-web"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-spectator"
    compile "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
    compile "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt"
    compile ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2") {
        exclude module: 'mapstruct'
    }
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators"
    compile "org.postgresql:postgresql"
    compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:${mapstruct_version}"
    testCompile "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-spring"
    testCompile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
    }
    testCompile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test"
    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core"
    testCompile "junit:junit"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library"
    testCompile "com.h2database:h2"
    optional ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor") {
        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
    }
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-dependency - JHipster will add additional dependencies here
}

task cleanResources(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/resources'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
}

task stage(dependsOn: 'bootRepackage') {
}

compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn cleanResources,bootBuildInfo
bootBuildInfo.mustRunAfter cleanResources
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What jhipster version are you using? The gradle wrapper version seems rather old. The war creation has been changed for jhipster 6. Doing ./gradlew -Pprod clean bootRepackage should create an executable(!) war file. It seems you are using jhipster 4.x, is that correct?

Comment: yes that correct i'm using "jhipsterVersion": "4.14.0",

Comment: What does ./gradlew tasks show you? As there is the war plugin you can either to bootRepackage which creates an executable war file or war which should create a war file that can be deployed in a container if I remember correctly.

Comment: this what ./gradlew task shows https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GIvVB3sVZ87AdjUr7xyqGG9PU-2h_GGY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I asked for ./gradlew tasks (with s). It shows all available tasks.

Comment: thx for ur time this what I got when I run ./gradlew tasks ttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1B5QLzlfyBPU1qFB2xS_traF7uptrw1UF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: SO from the output doing a gradlew war should give you a war which you can deploy in an application server. bootRepackage should create an executable war file which you ca execute via java -jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the answer more visible (valid for jhipster 4.x):

for creating a war that can be deployed in an application server use `./gradlew war` and for an executable war file, which can be executed via `java -jar` use `./gradlew bootWar`.